# I am trying to change the default folder for files downloaded using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to change the default folder where files are downloaded when I run a Selenium process.  I am testing the code below.

```
# download from web
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\my_desktop\\")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Utility/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get('https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/PWS/DownloadBulkData.aspx')
listproduct = ['Call Reports -- Single Period',
               'Call Reports -- Balance Sheet, Income Statement, Past Due -- Four Periods']

for product in listproduct:
    try:
        Weblistbox=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"ListBox1")))
        select=Select(Weblistbox)
        select.select_by_visible_text(product)
        print("Product {} is selected".format(product))
    
        for year in range(0,4):
            datedropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "DatesDropDownList")))
            select = Select(datedropdown)
            select.select_by_index(year)
            datedropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "DatesDropDownList")))
            select = Select(datedropdown)
            print("DateOrYear {} is selected".format(select.first_selected_option.text))
            WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'Download_0'))).click()
    except:
        print('out of range...')
```

Apparently the files are downloaded, according to what I see in the lower right hand corner of the browser, but I can't find the files after they are downloaded.  They don't go to the default downloads folder and they don't go to the alternative folder that I set.

I tried a slightly different version of code, shown below.  This, too, downloads all files to the standard/default 'C:\Users\ryans\Downloads'
folder.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Utility/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/PWS/DownloadBulkData.aspx')
listproduct = ['Call Reports -- Single Period',
               'Call Reports -- Balance Sheet, Income Statement, Past Due -- Four Periods']

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory": r"C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\my_desktop\\", "download.prompt_for_download": False, "download.directory_upgrade": True, "safebrowsing.enabled": True})
```

How can I get the files downloaded to a specific folder that I choose?  Thanks.